# access to related_name in ManyToManyField from it's model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

This is my model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="likes", symmetrical=False)
```

I want to show how many poeple like this post. for do this I need to access to related_name and show count it, but related_name just work with ForiegnKey.

I test these and don't worked:

```py
post.like.likes.count()
post.like.user_set.count()
```

Django: v4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`related_name` it's name of reverse relation. For example `like.likes.all()` will return all Post object.

You can check how many people like this post by this `post.like.count()`

BTW. In this example you set `related_name` to `posts`